# How to change the speed of ELCSlider

Tags: objective-c, xcode, audio-player

i have one ELCSlider as shown below in attachment.

here my problem is: i am repeating the timer for every 0.01, at that time my slider is moving slowly but i want to increase the speed of my slider for every 0.01 second.

can any one please let me how can do this.

[image]

Comment: i dont know completely but i can give you idea how to make that view

Comment: @krishna can you please tell me the way

Comment: mean to create the view as you shown in popup

Comment: @krishna not the creation, as i mentioned in my question what to know hoe to increase the speed of slider.